# Regular expression for AQL

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

```
2011-12-01T00:43:51.251871+05:18 Dec 01 2011 00:41:32 KOC-TEJ-AMEX-ASA-5510-6 : %ASA-4-106023: Deny icmp src TCS:172.26.40.1 dst AMEX:172.26.40.187 (type 5, code 0) by access-group "TCS_access_in" [0x953d065b, 0x0]
```

Need to extract `2011-12-01T00:43:51.251871+05:18`

My code

```
create view  standardLogTime as
extract regex /(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d+\w+\:\d{2}\:\d+\.\d+\+\d+\:\d+)/ on D.text as testValue
from Document D;
```

-- Extracting standard log generation time.

```
create view  standardLogTime as
extract regex /\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}T(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d+?\+\d{2}:\d{2}/ on D.text as      testValue
from Document D;

output view standardLogTime;
```

-- Extracting incoming request Date.

```
create view dateView as
extract regex /(\s+\w+\s\d+\s\d{4})/ on Date.text as testDate from Document Date;
```

--output view dateView;

-- Extracting incoming request Time.

```
create view timeView as
extract regex /\s+(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})/ on Time.text
as requestTime from Document Time;
```

--output view timeView;

-- Extracting the firewall device name.

```
 create view deviceName as
 extract regex /(\w+\-\w+\-\w+\-\w+\-\d+\-\d+)/ on Device.text
 as deviceName from Document Device;
```

--output view deviceName;

```
create view combinedView as
extract pattern (<S.testValue>) (<D.testDate>) (<T.requestTime>) (<Div.deviceName>)
return group 0 as logTime and
   group 1 as date and
   group 2 as time and
  group 3 as deviceName 
from standardLogTime S,dateView D ,timeView T,deviceName Div; 

 output view combinedView;*/
```

Comment: Will the desired extract always be at the start and always in this format?

Comment: yes. but i have to capture the details in other group also .        for date - (\s+\w+\s\d+\s\d{4}) like that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language that is, but in Python I would do

```
date = line.split()[0]
```

or, if I were forced to use an RE, it'd be

```
^(\S+)\s
```

Comment: I have to extract a lot of information from the logs , and i am search for a better and effecient way to extract this information.

Comment: @RohitHaritash: better than what? Better in what sense?

Comment: The problem is i have to combine all the group , like date,Time,Info. When i am combining the regular expressions , compiler say no match found. But each endividual regex is working. Please see me my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}T(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d+?\+\d{2}:\d{2}`